# Malware Allowing Remote Access to my Machine

Tags: malware, tcpip

I would like to understand how Malware allows a remote connection to my machine.

Am I correct in thinking that my modem / router will block all inbound connections from the internet? A scan has shown that no ports are open on my modem.

If Malware is installed on my machine, and someone accesses my machine to remote control it, won't that be an outbound connection from the malware phoning home, rather than an inbound connection? How does that work? How can this be detected?

Comment: This is a _very_ broad question, in which answers will vary on router, firewalls, ports open for gaming, software/malware installed on the computer, OS, etc. In fact you have multiple questions here. "How can this be detected?" = Anti-virus. Router will ***never*** block all inbound connections. Otherwise what's the point of a router? I voted to close this as too broad nonetheless. There are plenty of guides online that explain in detail.

Comment: Will it be an outbound connection or inbound? That is the question. Didn't think it was that broad. Outbound connection I can understand, but inbound I cannot understand if all the ports on my modem are closed. Please provide a guide that you would recommend.

Comment: Here: [serverfault what-does-incoming-and-outgoing-traffic-mean](http://serverfault.com/questions/443038/what-does-incoming-and-outgoing-traffic-mean)

Comment: Yeah I think the terminology is what is confusing in this case. I am talking about who is initiating / opening the connection rather than the actual data flow. Surely it would not be possible to open a connection coming in if all ports on router are closed.

Comment: When you connect to the internet you request data. This data somehow needs to get to you and thus some ports need to be open at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assertion that downloaded malware can initiate outbound traffic is correct. This is where anti-virus / anti-malware / software firewalls that monitor application traffic (or, maybe I should say "application access")/ common sense come into play; know what's running on the machine.

To answer some of the comments...It is possible for an application to dynamically open up port(s) for inbound traffic via uPnP/NAT-PMP, so this should be disabled at the router/gateway if you do not want that behavior. Assuming that it's disabled, inbound traffic to your machine should only work is if you forwarded ports to it.